# Binding problems - MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, binding

I have some problem with overall MVVM organisation. I have an AuthenticatedUser provided by a cloud api.This AuthenticatedUser User has fields like name, age....

I want to bind these to controls. I know I have to create properties that include the NotifyPropertyChanged in order to get this work.

Therefore I created a model that includes these properties and returned the fields from the AuthenticatedUser. The problem is that AuthenticatedUser is filling these fields with time. So the properties are not "set" in any way so there is also no notification for the bindings.

Here some code snippets:

```
public string Name // I want properties like this to bind to a textblock. The User object(provided by the cloud service) has these as fields. The Problem is that these are also changing so i have to update the binding!
    {
        get { return User.Name; }
    }
```

Comment: Would you care to share some code so that we can even begin to understand what your issue might be ?

Comment: added a little bit of code. The problem is that there is not much to show.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Are you having trouble figuring out when your login attempt has succeeded (or failed) to know when to fire PropertyChanged? If so, then this is a question about your cloud API, not about MVVM. Or are you having trouble firing your PropertyChanged events? If so, show the code you're trying and let us know what you expect it to do and what is or isn't happening.

Comment: It more a logical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your cloud api is taking some time to fetch AuthenticatedUser, so you can raise an Event on api finish in you callback method. Or you can define an Action as a callback, and then you bind the property.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @vape how come this doesn't provide answer to the question ?

Comment: So the best way in the MVVM pattern is a simple event?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `User` property implement `NotifyPropertyChanged` and then in your XAML bind to `User.Name`. This should work.

Alternatively you can invoke `NotifyPropertyChanged` for `Name` manually after setting the `User` property.

Comment: I don't have access to User

Comment: You must have, it is a property of your ViewModel from the code you posted

Comment: Yeah but I can't implement NotifyPropertyChanged because the User porperty is part of the cloud sdk

Comment: somewhere in your ViewModel there is something like `public AuthenticatedUser User {get; set;}` so what is the problem

Comment: But how can I bind to the Name property then, where I can't implement NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Does Name don't also need  a NotifyPropertyChanged?